MT3608 output voltage changing with input voltage
I recently made a small PCB with two MT3608 step-up converters on it, which are powered from a battery. I have two of them. One is for 5V and one for 3.3V.
Here is the problem:
When I power the converters with 3.7V from my power supply to simulate the battery, everything works fine. When I raise the voltage, the output voltage of the converter raises with it. If I lower the input voltage, the output voltage lowers too. I do not think that this is normal.
Here are the schematic and board layout:



Horrendous layout for a switching regulator. Might be unstable. And I think I see a unconnected airwire in there to those caps next to R8 (?)

The question doesn't seem to define the magnitude of the unwanted output voltage change. Do you have any oscilloscope captures of how the output voltage changes when the input voltage changes? That could help to get an answer.

@Unimportant. The unconnected airwaire was deleted by mistake. It is present in my PCB. And do you have any Tips on how to improve this layout?

You have a step-up converter.  As in larger output than input.  3.3V out < 3.7V in.  You have same circuit for both.  So it is hard to see When I power the converters with 3.7V from my power supply to simulate the battery, everything works fine.

The MT3608 is a boost converter (step-up), as you rightly mentioned. A boost converter increases the input voltage to a higher level, and you cannot have the input voltage higher than the output. When the input is 3.7V, the U7 (MT3608) boosts it to a 5V output, which is fine as you observed. For U6, it didn’t boost the voltage, and you obtained about 3.3V due to the forward voltage drop of the D8 Schottky diode. If you raise the voltage beyond 3.7V, the output of U6 will definitely rise with the input since the current will just flow through the L1 inductor and the D8 Schottky diode to the output. Similarly, the U7 output will rise above 5V when the input exceeds ~5.4V.
If your input is 3.7V, then I suggest you use 3.3V LDO (e.g., XC6206P332MR-G) for the 3.3V output. You can keep U7 for 5V.

+1. Also, if the input voltage is marginal/variable,  ~3 - 3.7 - 4.2V like from a Li-ion cell, the OP should use more advanced buck-boost/sepic converter, like TPS631010 or similar.

Oh, thats something I didnt think about! Thanks a Lot! I will try it out with a different converter!
